# REGEX Python find words that contain the string 'olo' but do not start or end with that string

Tags: python, regex

```
example_text = "Lorem ipsum dolorolo at sit amet, dolore dolor dolore"

re_pattern = r'(?!\bolo)(\wolo\w)(?!\w*olo\b)'
re_search = re.findall(re_pattern, example_text)
re_search
```

output is:

```
['dolor', 'dolor', 'dolor']
```

but it should be

```
['dolore', 'dolor', 'dolore']
```

for some reason the code ignores the last letter in two words

pls help me to fix code for correct output

Comment: Why it should be like `['dolore', 'dolor', 'dolore']` ?

Comment: a bit cheating but work with a _substring_ instead, smt like `example_text = example_text.removesuffix('olo').revomeprefix('olo')`

Comment: coz it should be full word, not just part of word

Comment: Like this? `\b(?!olo|\w*olo\b)\w*olo\w*` https://regex101.com/r/koygLv/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird tadaaaaam!! it is working correct now, big thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern, this assertion `(?!\w*olo\b)` should be before actually matching the text.

When matching the text, you should optionally repeat the word characters `\w*olo\w*`

You could write the pattern as:

```
\b(?!olo|\w*olo\b)\w*olo\w*
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right of the current position is not

  - `olo` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `\w*olo\b` Match optional word characters followed by olo and a word boundary
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `\w*olo\w*` Match olo between optional word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/koygLv/1)

---

Another option is to use a negative lookbehind after matching a word that contains olo, but does not end on olo:

```
\b(?!olo)\w*olo\w*\b(?<!olo)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mRNgBc/1)